# EXCEL, create a XML-file from a data in table via vba code

Tags: validation, excel, vba

**EXCEL**

The file luxom2xlm is available at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f3dd2aby8wxpn5x/AAAOqaUV9LvtgrNghMT71AkHa?dl=0

There are also screenshots (because I'm not allowed to insert pictures in it, I do not have 10 reputations ...  correction it seems that I was wrong)

[vba code to create a XML - https://www.dropbox.com/s/6vr30uydv9kmgqq/EXCEL_luxom_macro.PNG?dl=0](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6vr30uydv9kmgqq/EXCEL_luxom_macro.PNG?dl=0)

[formula doesn't work "inconsistent error" in excel2013- https://www.dropbox.com/s/mnpaurktpj39o21/EXCEL_luxom_columns.PNG?dl=0](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mnpaurktpj39o21/EXCEL_luxom_columns.PNG?dl=0)

(Unfortunately I just allowed to ask one question a day, so I'll open tomorrow a new question 
...)
(not the best solution for solving inconsistent problems but it is the only one I found till now - see comment)

**1. vba code : to create XML file**

I try to figure out 'how' to make macro to extract the data directly from a table and create a XML file and validate it via a XSD-file.
Manually it work fines, so I've recorded vba code.

But unfortunately this seem not to work.

```
' REF VBA   - http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=162:excel-vba-calling-sub-procedures-a-functions-placement-in-modules&catid=79&Itemid=475
'     EXCEL - http://excelcentral.com

Sub Export2XML()
'
' export2XML Macro
'
'  REF : http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/export-xml-data-HP010206401.aspx
'

'
    Path_Name = Sheets("info").Range("c21").Value ' Path_Name = E:\luxom.xml

    'work sheet luxom_input
    Sheets("luxom_input").Select

    'where Luxom__Elements_In_Output_Map is the root element of the XSD-file
    'which is used as reference

    'method 1 created via a record macro doesn't work
    ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("Luxom__Elements_In_Output_Map").export URL:= _
        "E:\luxom.xml"

    'method 2 
    ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("Luxom__Elements_In_Output_Map").export URL:= _
        Path_Name
End Sub
```

[image: I would like to make it dynamicaly, that is why I've entered]

**2. TABLE : formula not working INCONSISTENT ERROR** 
(the solution I found - see comment)

The formula worked fine in EXCEL2010, and in EXCEL2013 re-typed and recognised also but now I get an error
[image: formula]

Neither the help from microsoft solved my problem

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/mac-excel-help/correct-an-inconsistent-formula-HA102927556.aspx

Sheet "luxom_input", table "T_LuxomInput",

- in column "O - ID" (address = a fixed stringformat)

  `=CONCATENATE([@[networkID]] ;address; [@[groupID]] ;address; TEXT([@[HexAddress]];"00"))`
- in column "O - KAST"

  `=IF(AND(IFERROR(FIND(start_02;MID([@Name];1;1))>0;0);MID([@Name];2;1)<(CHAR(CODE(9)+1)));MID([@Name];2;1);"")`

Has somebody an idea to make it working ...

You may have to change `;` to `,` and `,` to `.` according to your local.

Comment: For "2. TABLE : formula not working INCONSISTENT ERROR ", I found a solution removing the column and just reenter the formula.

The reason why it doesn't work I didn't found a good reason, or why.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142523/creating-excel-macro-for-exporting-xml-to-a-certain-folder?rq=1[link] for part **1. MACRO : to create XML file** is the solution written by "nonprogrammer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[stackoverflow.com/questions/15142523/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142523/creating-excel-macro-for-exporting-xml-to-a-certain-folder?rq=1[link])… for part 1. MACRO : to create XML file is the solution written by "nonprogrammer" –  kris Aug 25 '14 at 16:21